# Safe to conduct apt-get autoremove in that situation

Tags: apt, gnome, package-management, 18.04

Is it possible for anyone to use list attached here (packages going to be removed by `apt-get autoremove`) for judgement if it safe to complete `apt-get autoremove`?
Question above arises as previous attempt to conduct autoremove completed in Bionic Beaver without graphical environment.

```
user@stationC:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  breeze-icon-theme fonts-dejavu fonts-dejavu-extra gir1.2-geocodeglib-1.0
  gnome-todo-common icoutils kde-runtime kde-runtime-data kde-style-breeze
  kde-style-breeze-qt4 kdelibs-bin kdelibs5-data kdelibs5-plugins kdiff3-doc
  kdoctools libattica0.4 libdlrestrictions1 libedataserverui-1.2-2 libgnome-todo
  libgpgme++2v5 libkactivities6 libkcmutils4 libkde3support4 libkdeclarative5
  libkdecore5 libkdesu5 libkdeui5 libkdewebkit5 libkdnssd4 libkemoticons4
  libkf5style5 libkfile4 libkhtml5 libkio5 libkjsapi4 libkjsembed4 libkmediaplayer4
  libknewstuff3-4 libknotifyconfig4 libkntlm4 libkparts4 libkpty4
  libkrosscore4 libktexteditor4 libkxmlrpcclient4 libntrack-qt4-1 libntrack0 libphonon4
  libplasma3 libpolkit-qt-1-1 libqca2 libqca2-plugins libqt4-qt3support
  libsolid4 libstreamanalyzer0v5 libstreams0v5 libthreadweaver4 ntrack-module-libnl-0
  oxygen-icon-theme phonon phonon-backend-gstreamer
  phonon-backend-gstreamer-common plasma-scriptengine-javascript
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 63 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
After this operation, 164 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

The goal is to preserve B. Beavers original graphical stack even if to do `apt-get autoremove`.

Comment: Is it *safe*? Yes, it won't cripple your base Ubuntu system. Is it *desirable*? Probably not, since it's not clear what your ultimate goal is. You might wind up reinstalling a bunch of those packages later.

Comment: Ultimate goal here is to prune all packages with zero reverse (upward)-dependencies. For apt-get autoremove to report zero removable packages. Exact as it was in 10.04 LTS prior to upgrading to B. Beaver.